# merge and sum 2 dataframes with some identical columns names

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes (pandas) where some columns have identical names, index is unique dates on both. I want to merge it into one dataframe where the columns that has identical names will be summed in the new merged dataframe and columns that are not identical will be kept as is.

Didn't try yet, looking for a general solution

Comment: Please post a sample of your data. If the dates are unique then how do you want the summing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you right. Here with a sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time1': ['2023-11-30', 
                              '2023-11-28', 
                              '2023-11-27', 
                              '2023-11-26', 
                              '2023-11-25'], 
                    'Data1': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time2': ['2023-11-30', 
                              '2023-11-29', 
                              '2023-11-28', 
                              '2023-11-27', 
                              '2023-11-20'], 
                    'Data1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'Data2': [62, 7, 5, 3, 10]})

df1 = df1.set_index('Time1')
df2 = df2.set_index('Time2')

df3 = pd.merge(left = df1, right = df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
df3.fillna(0, inplace=True)
# Sum and deletes duplicate columns
cols2drop =[] # this list will contain all columns to delete
for col in df3.columns: # iterate through column names
    if (col.endswith('_x')):
        col_stem = col[:len(col)-2] # create column stem
        df3[col_stem] = df3[col_stem + '_x'] + df3[col_stem + '_y'] # create new column with sum
        cols2drop.append(col_stem + '_x') # append column names to list
        cols2drop.append(col_stem + '_y')
df3.drop(columns=cols2drop, inplace=True) # delete now unneeded columns
df3

            Data2  Data1
2023-11-20   10.0    5.0
2023-11-25    0.0   10.0
2023-11-26    0.0    8.0
2023-11-27    3.0   10.0
2023-11-28    5.0    7.0
2023-11-29    7.0    2.0
2023-11-30   62.0    3.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a specific solution and your data sample is just what I was look for, but I need a general solution as I have hundreds of columns in my dataset. I was hoping  there is some built in functions that can do something like that. Or I will do some for loop to solve it.

Comment: See the above updated version. Now it will work with as many columns as there is